# Determine how the app has been launched - by user or by auto launch

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My Windows app can be launched by user or by autolaunch (registry, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run').

Is it possible to determine the way my app has been launched?

The only way that I found - to add command line parameters. Something like `myapp.exe -auto` and `myapp.exe -user`. Is it possible to avoid command line parameters?

Comment: Any particular reason as to why you would like to avoid command line args? I can't think of a cleaner way of doing what you're asking for.

Comment: You should have the facility that launches your application *tell you* its done so; a command line is the best option for this.   You would probably not bother with `-user` and assume that if there is no command line it was launched manually from the shell.

Comment: Use command line parameters. What's not to like about a system that is known to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *cleanest* approach is to use a command-line parameter that you include in the path specified in the `Run` Registry key.  Of course, there is nothing to stop the user from just running the app manually with the same command-line parameter.

Another option is to create a launcher that runs the main app.  Either create a launcher app that the Registry runs, or a launcher service that auto-starts with Windows and launches the main app whenever a user logs in.  Then you can do all kinds of things to let the main app detect when it is run from the launcher:

1. Make the two communicate with each other using pipes, window messages, etc.
2. Have the launcher pass a *secret* value in the `STARTUPINFO::lpReserved` or `STARTUPINFO::lpReserved2` field when calling `CreateProcess()` (see [this article](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undocumented-createprocess) for more details).
3. Make the main app check if its parent process ID is the launcher executable (and yes, there *IS* a concept of a parent process in Windows). See [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx) and [`Process32First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834.aspx)/[`Process32Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836.aspx). The [`PROCESSENTRY32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx) structure has a `th32ParentProcessID` field.  You can extract the filename associated with that process ID.
4. Make the launcher create a kernel object that the [launched process can inherit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724466.aspx).
5. etc, etc, etc.

But again, there is nothing to stop the user from just running the launcher manually, or killing a launcher service and writing a new launcher app to mimic the original behavior.

Best to just stick with the command-line parameter and don't worry about users trying to fake it out.  Basic users probably won't even know about the Registry or the command-line, and knowledgeable users will probably ignore them. Malicious users will likely figure out how to get around your detections, or just disable/replace them altogether.

Comment: It is a pity that we do not have the flag "Launched by the Windows via a string from Registry" ...

Comment: The only ways to pass info directly to an arbitrary launched process are command-line parameters and the `STARTUPINFO` structure. You don't want to use the command-line. Microsoft could define a new flag in `STARTUPINFO.dwFlags`, I suppose, but currently does not. A custom launcher can [hide secret data](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undocumented-createprocess) in `STARTUPINFO`, if the launched process knows where to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mohammed on this one - a command line flag seems to be the easiest, most extendable way to do what you're doing.

However, I have another idea (just for fun, I'm still for cmd args): you can register a different program in the registry which does whatever it is you wish to do differently and only than it will execute the original program. Like a registry bootstrapper.

Comment: Do note that neither solution is guaranteed to work as intended. A user could launch the application passing the *"launched automatically"* command line, or the launcher app, and have it behave as if this weren't a user-initiated launch.

Comment: Well, if the user wants to be evil, he is welcome to do that 

Comment: Does CreateProcess not launch things based on the file contents, whereas shellexecute executes based on the extension? so if the registered Run application did not have an executable extension, it would launch automatically, but the user could not run it..

Comment: @ChrisBecke: That wouldn't prevent a user from launching the application from the command prompt. The command prompt doesn't care about file extensions. And a user could simply fabricate a PowerShell script, a vbScript, or even just your average .cmd batch file to circumvent your protection scheme.

Comment: Nothing in the post implies that the method must resist evil users. Merely that we can detect the casual user double clicking an exe.